# Netplan in Debian

Tags: debian, networking, netplan

I'm a Ubuntu user trying out Debian 9.4. Since Ubuntu 17.10 I've been happily using netplan.

I do not use Network Manager, preferring to work with all the pieces myself.

**Edit after installing Buster**

Netplan is available in the Buster repo and runs just fine. The executable is installed to `/usr/sbin` which by default is not in the root path. `sudo` will find the executable or we can add `/usr/sbin` to root path.

Comment: Did you have an issue trying to use netplan?  It appears to be available in Debian 9: `apt-get install netplan`.

Comment: @GracefulRestart That netplan is a network interface to a day planner. The netplan I'm looking for is https://netplan.io/. This does not show up in the standard Debian 9 repos. So my question is: is there an issue with Debian and netplan? Is there any work on Debian and netplan? As a hobbyist I'm happy to tinker myself but I'm wondering about known issues.

Comment: oh, my mistake.  I am not a debian or netplan user and just saw the same name package in the repository.  That is an unfortunate name and makes searching difficult.  After checking out [the netplan source](https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/netplan), I was able to build it using Debian 9.  I ran the tests, but i think due to the nature of my test machine, I cannot get them all to pass.  I have not found anyone else trying to use this on Debian, but I have not seen anything yet that would prevent anyone from getting it to work.

Comment: I took the source from github too but am having trouble building it. I haven't much experience with building C. Just some stuff on VAX VMS a hundred years ago.  I'm opening another question hoping for help with that. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: If there's flatpak or snapd support in debian, you might find your netplan there.

Comment: @StephenBoston: as far as your question is phrased `netplan.io` == `netplan` (i.e. if you do `man netplan` you get the "right" one). It's utterly unclear *from the question* which one you are talking about and your edit added to the confusion, I have to say. Or do you *really* refer to [this](http://www.bitrot.de/plan.html) which is packaged as `netplan` on both [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=netplan) and [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=netplan)?

Comment: @0xC0000022L Thank you for the correction! I had successfully  installed 'netplan' from the Debian repository but calling netplan from the commandline did not have the effect I expected. On looking at the man page I saw that it was networked planning software.  After building and installing from github all was well. Now either I was dreaming, made some error, or there has been a change. Either way you are quite right and I will edit my question. Once again thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/netplan and installed that. It is working. I haven't rigorously tested it at all but it does what I need. The build required these libraries. This is covered in [debian netplan install: library missing. what to install for these .pc files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/438838/debian-netplan-install-library-missing-what-to-install-for-these-pc-files)

But I'll put the outcome of that discussion here:

```
# to compile

apt install libyaml-dev -y 
apt install libc6-dev -y
apt install libglib2.0-dev -y
apt install pandoc -y
apt install uuid-dev -y

#to run
pip3 install pyyaml 
pip3 install netifaces
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like netplan.io in Debian is at a very early stage.  There is an "Intend to package" bug, See https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=882661 but no traffic there so far to gauge progress.

Comment: Update for mid 2019:

As of Debian 10/Buster [netplan.io][1] is in the default Debian repos. I haven't used it (personally I prefer manual config via the old school /etc/network/interfaces file) but I imagine that it should work as expected...


  [1]: https://packages.debian.org/buster/netplan.io

Comment: @JeremyDavis Installed from Buster repo. netplan installs its executable to `/usr/sbin` which in my new installation is not in the root path. `sudo` finds it so those who find `sudo for everything root ` to be just wrong will add `/usr/sbin` to root path.