# debian netplan install: library missing. what to install for these .pc files

Tags: debian, compiling

First attempt to build netplan.io on Debian 9 and have the errors below. Can you tell me what I need to install?

```
Package yaml-0.1 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing  

`yaml-0.1.pc'   

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'yaml-0.1' found

Package uuid was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing 

`uuid.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'uuid' found
```

Neither of the pkgconfig directories under /usr contain these .pc files. And the pc files do not show up on a wider search.

Please, what do I need to install?

There is also this :

```
src/generate.c:24:18: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <glib.h>
```

however there is a glib-2.0.pc in the usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/ directory. Is there a misconfiguration?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After taking

https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/netplan.git

Need to install :

```
libyaml-dev 
libc6-dev
libglib2.0-dev
pandoc
uuid-dev
```

Thanks to @dsstorefile and @user996142

To run netplan will require :

```
pip3 install pyyaml
```

For Debian 10, need also

```
pip3 install netifaces
```